# Image swap when hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a snippet to swap images between no underscore and '_1' in the source path when hovering and leaving the .hover()

Sometimes I see an issue whereby the next image I hover over get's the 'styled' image from the previous image i hovered over (this is inconsistent!) with '_1'?

I think it has to do with the speed at which you hover over the images.

I'm using $(this) to refer to the div the user is currently hovering over and maybe it's inconsistently storing the src for the img and referencing it too soon?

Please see below a video demonstrating my issue:
http://screencast.com/t/lJEDb5lyTXj5

PS: I don't have access to the source code - I am injecting this code onto the site, (So i can't manipulate the divs/images without JS)

```
<head>
<style>
.js div.result.product {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script>
    $('html').addClass('js');

</script>
<script>

   $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('div.result.product').show();

    });

  </script>
</head>
<script> 

    console.log($('div.result-image').length);

  // Function to set all images with _1 to no "_1".
  $( "div.result-image > a > img" ).each(function() {
      console.log('one image');

    var styled = "_1";
    var revertStyledOriginal = $(this).attr('src');
    var preset = "?hei=245&qlt=85,1&wid=245&fmt=jpeg&resMode=bicub&op_sharpen=1";


    // if the img is silo
    var s = revertStyledOriginal;

    // Only takes everything up until the "_"
    unstyle = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('_'));


    // add the preset back onto the src to make the img crisp
    var unstyled = unstyle + preset;
    // sets this instance of the image in the each loop to the "new link" with removed "_1"  
    $(this).attr('src', unstyled);



});



 // Hover Function

    $('div.result.product').hover(function myfunc() {
        //Store 'this' as a reference to the current product image to be referred to when switching images
        var selection = $(this);


    $link = selection.find('img').attr('src');
    $parsed = $link;
    var styled = "_1";



    var revertStyledOriginal = selection.find('img').attr('src');
    var preset = "?hei=245&qlt=85,1&wid=245&fmt=jpeg&resMode=bicub&op_sharpen=1";


  //if the img is silo
  if(revertStyledOriginal.indexOf(styled) === -1 && ($link !== "http://www.kirklands.com/assets/HTML/MVS/AB_tests/NextPageButton/Next_Page_Buttons_Page_2.jpg")) 
  { 
  $preset = "?hei=245&qlt=85,1&wid=245&fmt=jpeg&resMode=bicub&op_sharpen=1";

    //Need to remove preset to add _1 (then readd preset).

    $removedPreset = $parsed.substring(0, $parsed.indexOf('?'));
    var Unstyled = $removedPreset + $preset;
    var Styled = $removedPreset + "_1" + $preset;


function checkImage(src) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    // code to set the src on success
        selection.find('img').attr('src', Styled)
     //console.log('exists');
     //console.log(revertStyledOriginal);

  };
  img.onerror = function() {
            selection.find('img').attr('src', Unstyled)
        console.log('doesnt exist');
        //console.log();

  };

  img.src = src; // fires off loading of image
}

checkImage(Styled);

}

//if the img is styled
else {}

//$( this ).attr("src",); 
},
//Function to reset the image on when you exit hover of img
function() {

        $original = $(this).find('img').attr('src')
        $removedPreset = $parsed.substring(0, $parsed.indexOf('?'));
        $link = $removedPreset + $preset;

        if ($original !== "http://www.kirklands.com/assets/HTML/MVS/AB_tests/NextPageButton/Next_Page_Buttons_Page_2.jpg")  {
    // set on hover image src to silo
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', $link)
        }
});



</script>
```

Comment: You probably don't need Javascript to do this. Set the image as a background in CSS and then override the image in the `:hover` psuedo-class.

Comment: Hey David, yeah - i'd like to do that, but i can't actually edit the source code or how it's handled like that, I have to inject code to manipulate what is already there, I also have to check to make sure sure the image exists first so i can't really only use CSS.

Comment: You can inject your own CSS rules in addition to exising using Javascript, and make it possible to swap background images using pure CSS, take a look at [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets).